# Breaking apart a large amount of text in VIM by pattern

Tags: vim

I have a large amount of text that is formatted like:

```
123123|abcabc|text
text
text
123124|abcabc|text
textext
text
```

The goal is to get the text to by arranged like this:

```
123123|abcabc|texttexttext
123124|abcabc|texttext text
```

So that each entry is place onto its own line followed by a carriage return separating it from the next line.

I've tried to do something like search for the `|` symbol, and then I made a macro to search for every 3rd `|` symbol, go to the previous word, and insert a carriage turn.

```
nnnbi<CR><Esc>
```

but I couldn't get it to repeat. I'm a very new user, any direction would be hugely helpful.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this command could help you:

```
g/|/j3
```

if you don't want to have the spaces after the join, add a "bang[!]".

```
g/|/j!3
```

see `:h :join` for details

**EDIT**

then this line should work

```
:v/|/-1 j!
```

or another option would work too:

```
:v/|/normal! I^U
```

note that the `^U` you should press <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, Kent, for your help! Unfortunately, the amount of text in each field is variable, so some fields are 20-30 lines, and the others are 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use `:v` with pattern `|` that will execute next command for every line that doesn't contain a pipe. The command will be `X` that deletes character previous to cursor position, and because cursor always will be in first line it deletes previous newline character that will join both lines, and so on until the end:

```
:v/|/normal X
```

It yields:

```
123123|abcabc|texttexttext
123124|abcabc|texttextexttext
```

Comment: I think you have a customized `'whichwrap'` option. default is `b,s`, `X` won't work linewise.

Comment: @Kent: You are right. I have customized it in my `vimrc` like `set whichwrap+=<,>,[,],h,l`. Good point for whoever who wanted to try this solution. Thanks.

Comment: if you get used to this setting, you will have headache if you played vimgolf. :D